# Trying to limit the drawing of Kinetic polygons based on distance from center of stage

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am trying to draw a grid of polygons in a circle programmatically. Im trying to do this by using the coordinates on the canvas element in the Pythagorean theorem:

```
function createTri(x, y) { //This function works correctly without the if statement.

    var tri = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        width: 11,
        height: 11,
        fillRed: 17,
        fillGreen: 17,
        fillBlue: 17,
        closed: true,
        shadowColor: '#5febff',
        shadowBlur: 3,
        shadowOpacity: 0.18
    });

    if ((Math.abs(Math.pow(x, 2)) + Math.abs(Math.pow(y, 2))) < Math.pow(radius, 2)) { //This causes the squares not to be drawn.
        layer.add(tri);
    };
}
```

How the function SHOULD work is the squares should only be drawn if their coordinates are less than the radius, however no triangles are drawn at all.

If I take out the `if` statement, the rest of my code draws the squares correctly in a grid covering the page as it should.

My complete code for the population of the squares is this:

```
var xt = stage.width() / 2;

var yt = stage.height() / 2;

var radius = 300;

var pax = [];

//Pushes the coordinates to the 3D Array (This works correctly)
for (var i = 0; i < stage.height() / 12; i++) {
    pax[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < stage.width() / 12; j++) {
        pax[i][j] = [];
        pax[i][j].push(j * 12 - (stage.width() / 2) + xt, i * -12 + (stage.height() / 2) + yt);
    };
}

function createTri(x, y) { //This function works correctly without the if statement.

    var tri = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        width: 11,
        height: 11,
        fillRed: 17,
        fillGreen: 17,
        fillBlue: 17,
        closed: true,
        shadowColor: '#5febff',
        shadowBlur: 3,
        shadowOpacity: 0.18
    });

    if ((Math.abs(Math.pow(x, 2)) + Math.abs(Math.pow(y, 2))) < Math.pow(radius, 2)) { //This causes the squares not to be drawn.
        layer.add(tri);
    };
}


//drawing triangles to correct grid coordinates (This works properly)
for (var i = 0; i < pax.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < pax[i].length; j++) {
        createTri(pax[i][j][0], pax[i][j][1]);
    };
}
```

Everything looks correct, so Im not sure where Im going wrong with the `if` statement.

Comment: First: see if replacing your if statement with this works: `if (Math.hypot(x, y) < radius) { //...`.

Comment: Actually, try this: `if (Math.abs(x) * Math.sqrt(1 + (x / y) * (x / y)) < radius) { // ...`. Math.hypot is an ES6 function.